# Vue-Router get Props from Router-Function

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I have a route as follows:

```js
{
        path: '/tabs',
        name: 'Tabs',
        component: Tabs,
        children: [
            {
                path: 'test/:id',
                name: 'Test-View',
                component: () => import('@/views/subviews/Test.vue'),
                props: (route) => ({ id: route.params.id, label: 'Label from Route' })
            },
            {
                path: 'test-two/:id',
                name: 'Test-View-Two',
                component: TestTwo,
                props: { label: 'Test12' }
            }
        ]
    },
```

And a `Tabs`-Component that builds a Tab-View from the child-routes:

```js
<template>
    <div class="router-tabs">
        <div class="tabs">
            <router-link v-for="(route, index) in childRoutes" :key="index" class="tab" :to="route">
                <span v-if="route.props != undefined && route.props.label">{{ route.props.label }}</span>
                <span v-if="route.props == undefined || !route.props.label">No Label</span>
            </router-link>
        </div>
        <router-view />
    </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { Component, Vue, Prop } from 'vue-property-decorator';

@Component
export default class RouterTabs extends Vue {
    public get childRoutes() {
        const childRoutes = this.$router.options.routes?.find((route) => route.name === this.$route.name || route.children?.find((child) => child.name === this.$route.name))?.children;
        return childRoutes;
    }
}
</script>
```

As stated in the first child-route the Props-Property is a function.
How can I get the `label`-Prop in my Tabs-Component?

Currently the label of the first Tab/Route is alway `undefined` respectively an error is thrown.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, got the solution.

The issue is to use the Prop-Field for static values.
Now I use the `meta`-Property to pass the information.

```js
<template>
    <div class="router-tabs">
        <div class="tabs">
            <router-link v-for="(route, index) in childRoutes" :key="index" class="tab" :to="route">
                <span v-if="route.meta != undefined && route.meta.label">{{ route.meta.label }}</span>
                <span v-if="route.meta == undefined || !route.meta.label">No Label</span>
            </router-link>
        </div>
        <router-view />
    </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { Component, Vue, Prop } from 'vue-property-decorator';

@Component
export default class RouterTabs extends Vue {
    public get childRoutes() {
        const childRoutes = this.$router.options.routes?.find((route) => route.name === this.$route.name || route.children?.find((child) => child.name === this.$route.name))?.children;
        return childRoutes;
    }
}
</script>
```